# Change ProgramName for SQL Server connection pool

Tags: sql-server, oracle, postgresql, properties, connection

I trying to identify the corporate users using the connections from the connection pool (C3P0) in a JAVA EE application. I executing the statement to set connection info before I give the connection to hibernate and setting it to empty string when the connection is returned to the pool.

For PostgreSQL:

```
SET application_name TO 'MyCorporateSystem - Billing - John Doe';
```

For Oracle:

```
call DBMS_SESSION.SET_IDENTIFIER('MyCorporateSystem - Billing - John Doe');
```

Microsoft SQL Server also has a ProgramName column on 'sp_who2', but it seems that you cannot set it after the connection has been made, only in the connection string, is that correct? The only way is to use `CONTEXT_INFO` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. This cannot be changed in t-sql. It is part of the connection string.